# attack against Persia (Iran) in the Acharis HaYomim

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, ymoth-hamoshiach

I saw a midrash that says that Edom (Europe, US?) will join forces with Arabia; together they
will attack Malchus Poras (Persia, Iran).After they defeat her, they will in turn attack
Yisrael, leading to the coming of Moshiach.
I believe that I saw this in the Yalkut Shimoni, but I don't remember where.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Arnold and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Maybe in a commentary on Zech. 14?

Comment: Not completely it, but refer to the Zohar: http://www.kabbalah.info/eng/content/view/frame/86459?/eng/content/view/full/86459&main

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.499.1?lang=bi&with=all

Answer (score 5):

I saw it in [Pesikta Rabbasi 36:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesikta_Rabbati.36.1?vhe=OYW&lang=bi&lookup=%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D&with=Lexicon&lang2=en):

> אמר רבי יצחק שנה שמלך המשיח נגלה בו כל מלכי האומות העולם מתגרים זה בזה מלך פרס מתגרה במלך ערביא והולך מלך ערביא לאדום ליטול עצה מהם (והחזיר) [וחוזר] מלך פרס (והחריב) [ומחריב] את כל העולם כולו וכל אומות העולם מתרעשים ומתבהלים ונופלים על פניהם ויאחוז אותם צירים כצירי יולדה וישראל מתרעשים ומתבהלים ואומרים להיכן נלך ולהיכן נבוא ואומר להם בניי אל תתייראו [כל מה שעשיתי לא עשיתי אלא בשבילכם מפני מה אתם מתייראים אל תיראו] הגיע (ימי) [זמן] גאולתכם ולא כגאולה ראשונה כך גאולה אחרונה כי גאולה ראשונה היה לכם צער ושיעבוד מלכיות (אחרים) [אחריה] אבל גאולה אחרונה אין לכם צער ושיעבוד מלכיות (אחרים) [אחריה]
>
> Rabbi Yitzchak said, when the Melech HaMoshiach will be revealed all the kings of the nations of the world will be in conflict with one another. The King of Persia will be in conflict with the king of Arabia, and the king of Arabia will go to the King of Edom to seek advice from them, and the King of Persia will return and destroy all the world, and all the nations of the world tremble and panic and fall on their faces, and they are gripped by pain like that of labour pains, and Israel trembles and panics. And they say, "Where will we go?" and "Where will we come?" and I say to them, "My sons do not be afraid". [All that I did, I did only for you. For what are you afraid of, don't be afraid]. The time of your redemption has come, and it won't be as a first redemption, but a final redemption; because the first redemption was painful for you and (resulted in) the enslavement of (other) kingdoms [after it], but the last redemption - you will not have pain nor the enslavement of (other) kingdoms [after it].